# How to configure gl:ortho for the size of window in cl-opengl

Tags: opengl, common-lisp

I'm try configure `gl:ortho` for the size of window in the cl-opengl, but don't work:

```lisp
(gl:viewport 0 0 (width window) (height window))
(gl:matrix-mode :projection)
(gl:ortho (- (/ (width window) 2)) (/ (width window) 2) (- (/ (height window) 2)) (/ (height window) 2) -1.0 1.0)
(gl:matrix-mode :modelview)
(gl:load-identity)
```

With:

```lisp
(width window) => 800
(height window) => 600
```

If I draw one triangle with the vertices below:

```lisp
(verts #(0.0 280.0
         -280.0 -280.0
         280.0 -280.0))
```

I get the whole blue screen. But if I try with the coordinates below:

```lisp
(verts #(0.0 0.8
         -0.8 -0.8
         0.8 -0.8))
```

I get the blue triangle in the screen as if it hadn't configured anything in `gl:ortho`.

Where did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work, the secret is that you need to multiply the projection matrix by the position in the vertex-shader, like is showed below:

The functions common for the both next examples:

```
(require :sdl2)
(require :cl-opengl)
(require :cl-glut)

(defun runtime-load-shader (shader-type shader-src)
  (let ((shader (gl:create-shader shader-type)))
    (gl:shader-source shader shader-src)
    (gl:compile-shader shader) 
    shader))

(defun alloc-array-buffer (verts)
  (let ((array-buffer (gl:gen-buffer))
    (arr (gl:alloc-gl-array :float (length verts))))
    (gl:bind-buffer :array-buffer array-buffer)
    (dotimes (i (length verts))
      (setf (gl:glaref arr i) (aref verts i)))
    (gl:buffer-data :array-buffer :static-draw arr)
    (gl:free-gl-array arr)
    array-buffer))

(defun create-new-program (program)
  (let ((verts #(0.0 280.0
         -280.0 -280.0
         280.0 -280.0))
    (vs (runtime-load-shader :vertex-shader "#version 120

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
attribute vec2 coord2d;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);
}
"))
    (fs (runtime-load-shader :fragment-shader "#version 120

void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor[0] = 0.0;
  gl_FragColor[1] = 0.0;
  gl_FragColor[2] = 1.0;
}
"))
    (coord2d nil))
    (gl:attach-shader program vs)
    (gl:attach-shader program fs)
    (gl:link-program program)
    (alloc-array-buffer verts)
    (setf coord2d (gl:get-attrib-location program "coord2d"))
    (gl:use-program program)
    (gl:enable-vertex-attrib-array coord2d)
    (gl:vertex-attrib-pointer coord2d
                      2
                      :float
                      :false
                      0
                      (cffi:null-pointer))))

(defun draw-triangle ()
  (gl:draw-arrays :triangles 0 3))

(defun program-shutdown (program)
  (gl:delete-program program))
```

An example drawing a triangle with cl-glut:

```
(defclass glut-test-window (glut:window)
  ((program :accessor program)) 
  (:default-initargs :width 800 :height 600
             :mode '(:double :rgb :depth) :title "shader-vao-test"))

(defmethod glut:display-window :before ((w glut-test-window))
  (setf (program w) (gl:create-program))
  (create-new-program (program w)))

(defmethod glut:display ((w glut-test-window))
  (gl:clear-color 0.0 0.0 0.2 1.0)
  (gl:clear :color-buffer-bit)
  (draw-triangle)
  (glut:swap-buffers))

(defmethod glut:reshape ((w glut-test-window) width height)
  (gl:viewport 0 0 800 600)
  (gl:matrix-mode :projection)
  (gl:load-identity)
  (gl:ortho -400 400 -300 300 -1.0 1.0)
  (when (program w)
      (let ((proj-mat (gl:get-float :projection-matrix)))
    (gl:uniform-matrix 
     (gl:get-uniform-location (program w) "projectionMatrix") 
     4 
     (vector proj-mat))))
  (gl:matrix-mode :modelview)
  (gl:load-identity))

(defmethod glut:keyboard ((w glut-test-window) key x y)
  (declare (ignore x y))
  (case key
    (#\Esc (glut:destroy-current-window))))

(defun glut-test ()
  (let ((w (make-instance 'glut-test-window)))
    (glut:display-window w)
    (program-shutdown (program w))))

(glut-test)
```

An example drawing a triangle with cl-sdl2:

```
(defun sdl2-test ()
  (sdl2:with-init (:everything)
    (sdl2:with-window (win :flags '(:shown :opengl))
      (sdl2:with-gl-context (gl-context win)
        (let ((program (gl:create-program)))
      (create-new-program program)

          (gl:viewport 0 0 800 600)
      (gl:matrix-mode :projection)
      (gl:load-identity)
      (gl:ortho -400 400 -300 300 -1.0 1.0)
      (when program
        (let ((proj-mat (gl:get-float :projection-matrix)))
          (gl:uniform-matrix 
           (gl:get-uniform-location program "projectionMatrix") 
           4 
           (vector proj-mat))))
      (gl:matrix-mode :modelview)
      (gl:load-identity)

      (sdl2:with-event-loop (:method :poll)
            (:idle ()
                   (gl:clear :color-buffer)
                   (gl:color 1.0 0.0 0.0)
           (draw-triangle)
                   (sdl2:gl-swap-window win))

            (:quit () t)))))))
(sdl2-test)
```

The sad thing is to have to multiply the projection matrix on all shaders.